# On CentOS Certbot / Lets Encrypt uses snap to keep SSL certificates up to date. Is there another method that will keep certificates up to date?

Tags: centos, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot, centos8

**Environment:** Centos 8, Certbot, Lets Encrypt

On CentOS distributions certbot / Lets Encrypt uses snap to keep SSL certificates up to date.  Below are the instructions.

[certbot instructions: Nginx on CentOS/RHEL 8](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/centosrhel8-nginx.html)

```
$ sudo snap install core; sudo snap refresh core

$ sudo ln -s /snap/bin/certbot /usr/bin/certbot

$ sudo certbot --nginx
```

However in a comment to [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/1054551/555422) Michael Hampton indicated that snap is not commonly used for Centos distributions and not necessarily needed for this job.

> This isn't really an issue on CentOS where the packages are kept up to
> date. You could try to use the snap, but snap is largely yet another
> technologically questionable Canonical thing and most everyone else in
> the world ignores it.

How might certbot / Lets Encrypt be set up on CentOS / NGINX so that a certificate is downloaded and kept up to date without snap?  I'm beginning to realize that the fewer technologies I use the less chance something might go wrong in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[certbot](https://centos.pkgs.org/8/epel-aarch64/certbot-1.12.0-1.el8.noarch.rpm.html) is available on EPEL. Follow these [instructions](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) to add the Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL) to your system. After that certbot can be installed like any other package with `yum install certbot`.

The certbot package is then updated along with the other packages on the system when running `yum update`.

Comment: Isn't certbot just a utility?  Even if it's kept up to date that wouldn't necessarily mean that the certs it installed are kept up to date.  Or do I understand certbot incorrectly?

Comment: That's true. But snap is only about updating the certbot package itself, not certificates. You need a cronjob for that. The package comes with `certbot-renew.service`. Check that, I guess it takes care of that.

Comment: Or rather you should enable and start `certbot-renew.timer`, which will start the renew service periodically.